# How to position the Highcharts.StockChart's rangeSelector zoom on the right?

Tags: highcharts

My question is very simple: 
How to position the Highcharts.StockChart's rangeSelector zoom on the right?

[Its default](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/) is left. I couldn't find any documentation regarding it. Only how to position the input text elements of the [inputBoxStyle](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#rangeSelector)

Comment: I cannot find any way to influence the position. I think the answer is: You can't.

Comment: See this though for how to change the source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15409915/1171043

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change only the input and labels position.
If you want to change the buttons position you have to change the source code.

Comment: I was afraid someone will say that.