# Is it possible to position the zoom buttons in highcharts/highstock?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

As the title says, we have some charts that have two y axis on the left, and as a consequence if the screen is made smaller then the zoom buttons overlap the range inputs.

Ideally I would want the zoom buttons to always align to the left of the chart (including axis)

Thanks

[image]

I can't find anything in the API to suggest it's possible http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector

Comment: why would I need a code snippet? I'm asking if there is any code to do it!

Comment: Stack Overflow is also the official way to ask questions about highcharts and highstock, I'm not just going to include a useless code snippet. If you know about highcharts then this question would make sense without a code snippet.

Comment: I think you can find your answer in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409914/how-to-position-rangeselector-zoom-buttons-at-custom-co-ordinates-in-highstock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this: [How to position RangeSelector / zoom buttons at custom co-ordinates in Highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409914/how-to-position-rangeselector-zoom-buttons-at-custom-co-ordinates-in-highstock)

```
var orgHighchartsRangeSelectorPrototypeRender = Highcharts.RangeSelector.prototype.render;
Highcharts.RangeSelector.prototype.render = function (min, max) {
    orgHighchartsRangeSelectorPrototypeRender.apply(this, [min, max]);
    var leftPosition = this.chart.plotLeft,
        topPosition = this.chart.plotTop+5,
        space = 2;
    this.zoomText.attr({
        x: leftPosition,
        y: topPosition + 15
    });
    leftPosition += this.zoomText.getBBox().width;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; i++) {
        this.buttons[i].attr({
            x: leftPosition,
            y: topPosition 
        });
        leftPosition += this.buttons[i].width + space;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 14):

By default, the scale reset button located on the right. You can change position by using this code, for example:

```
...
chart: {
    zoomType: 'x, y',
    resetZoomButton: {
        position: {
            align: 'left', // right by default
            verticalAlign: 'top', 
            x: 10,
            y: 10
        },
        relativeTo: 'chart'
    }
}    
...
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aleksey_Bykov/yugz6wsh/).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any options to move the buttons, but you can move the range inputs using:

```
        rangeSelector: {
            inputPosition: {
                x: 100
            }
        },
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.inputPosition.

Parhaps you can move the input boxes to the left hand side, or remove them altogether ?

Comment: not really an option I'm afraid, we need both on there (client request), It's looking like we might need to write something from scratch