# Highcharts StockChart rangeSelector not displayed correctly for initially hidden chart

Tags: highcharts

I have two charts on one page, first of them is initially hidden. When I switch to hidden one, range selector buttons are not displayed correctly. Below are images that will be the best description of this problem:

This is the first tab with correct ranges display:

[image: this is ok]

and this one has everything moved to right (buttons over 'zoom' text, labels in buttons, dates outside datebox):

[image: this is wrong]

I've seen [How to position RangeSelector / zoom buttons at custom co-ordinates in Highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409914/how-to-position-rangeselector-zoom-buttons-at-custom-co-ordinates-in-highstock) and similar solutions of customising ranges display, but I don't want to modify it, I just need them to display correctly.

I tried to force re-rendering of this chart, but nothing helped so far. I will appreciate any suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: Could you reprorudce your issue as live demo?

Comment: I realised that this was related to twitter bootstrap tab that we've used - we had a hidden tab to render the chart, but there were some styles that weren't working there... Fix was simple, but time to find the bug quite long...

Comment: @santuxus can you recall the fix ? I am having same problem now..need help...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember the details and I don't have access to this code anymore... In general it wasn't related to highcharts itself, but to the styles we've used.